# Firebird 3 multiple insert

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

Can I do multiple insert with Firebird 3:

```sql
INSERT INTO ECHELONS (N_EMPLOYE, ECHELON, INDICE, "DATE", TYPE_PROMO,NOTE, REMARQUE) VALUES( @P10, @P11, @P12, @P13, @P14, @P15, @P16); 
INSERT INTO ECHELONS (N_EMPLOYE, ECHELON, INDICE, "DATE", TYPE_PROMO,NOTE, REMARQUE) VALUES( @P790, @P791, @P792, @P793, @P794, @P795, @P796);
```

or that:

```sql
INSERT INTO ECHELONS (N_EMPLOYE, ECHELON, INDICE, "DATE", TYPE_PROMO,NOTE, REMARQUE) VALUES( @P10, @P11, @P12, @P13, @P14, @P15, @P16),( @P790, @P791, @P792, @P793, @P794, @P795, @P796);
```

I am using C# and I get this error:

Error:

```
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 117
INSERT
```

and
What if I did it like this (performance wise):

```
 FbTransaction fbTransaction = fb.BeginTransaction() ;
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
          FbCommand fbCommand = new FbCommand();           
          fbCommand.Transaction = fbTransaction;
          fbCommand.Connection = fb;
          fbCommand.CommandText = insertSql;
          fbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   fbTransaction.Commit();
```

In casse of multiple accesse to the DB ,will that give me any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this directly.

Your first attempt is not possible, because you can only execute **one** statement at a time, not two. Unless you use the `FbScript` component, but then you cannot parameterise.

Your second attempt is not possible, because Firebird unfortunately does not support the table value constructor with more than one row.

Your options are:

1. Prepare a single statement and use the batch execution facility introduced in the [ADO.NET provider 9.0.0.0 for Firebird](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233896-ado-net-provider-9-0-0-0-for-firebird-is-ready-with-entity-framework-core-6-0-support). I have no experience with this API itself, so I can't demonstrate how to use it. It is also - as far as I understand - a low-level API right now, so it might need more polish for usability.
2. Use [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml-execblock.html) with multiple statements, e.g. something like

   ```
   execute block (p10 integer = ?, p11 varchar(50) = ?, p20 integer = ?, p21 varchar(50) = ?)
   as
   begin
     insert into sometable(col1, col2) values (:p10, :p11);
     insert into sometable(col1, col2) values (:p20, :p21);
   end
   ```

This second option comes with a number of limitations, for example the size of all parameters together cannot exceed 64 kilobytes, so if you have very wide rows to insert, this will limit the number of rows you can insert in a single block.